# Mezclar dos arrays en uno. Java

Tags: java, array

soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion, estoy intentando mezclar dos arrays en uno, cada uno con la dimension que nosotros elijamos, y se rellena con randoms. Pero a la hora de mezlarlos, imprimiendo el primero del primer array, primero del segundo array, segundo del primer array, segundo del segundo array.. etc, me da una excepción cuando se imprime.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>     at arrays.Ej_5.main(Ej_5.java:34).

¿Alguna ayuda?

```
package arrays;
import java.util.*;

public class Ej_5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce la dimension del primer array");
        int n=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce la dimension del segundo array");
        int d=input.nextInt();

        int[] p_array= new int[n];
        int[] s_array= new int[d];

        for (int i=0;i<p_array.length;i++){
            p_array[i]= (int)(Math.random()*10);
            System.out.print(p_array[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int j=0;j<s_array.length;j++){
            s_array[j]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
            System.out.print(s_array[j] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        int[] mezcla = new int [(n+d)-1];
        for (int k=0;k<mezcla.length;k++){
            System.out.print(p_array[k] + " ");
            System.out.print(s_array[k] + " ");
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: espero mi solución te ayude

Comment: me comentas como te fue con mi solución

Comment: funciona bien gracias

Comment: no hay problema, no te olvides de marcar mi respuesta como aceptada y voto arriba :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro, porque estás tratando de leer un indice del array que no existe, mira:

```
p_array = longitud = n
s_array = longitud = d
mezcla  = longitud = n + d - 1 

  int[] mezcla = new int [(n+d)-1];  
    for (int k=0;k<mezcla.length;k++){
        //aquí el error, va a llegar un momento que k > n y cae
        // también k > d y cae
        System.out.print(p_array[k] + " ");
        System.out.print(s_array[k] + " ");
    }
```

Lo que deberías hacer sería algo como esto:

```
int[] mezcla = new int [(n+d)-1];

//llena tu array mezcla con p_array (n) y s_array (d) 
int indice = 0;
int indiceParray = 0;
int indiceSarray= 0 ;
for (int x=0;x<mezcla.length;x++){
   //si es elemento par
   if (x%2 == 0 && indiceParray < p_array.length -1){
     mezcla[x] =  p_array[indiceParray];
     indiceParray++;
   } else if(indiceSarray < s_array.length -1){
     mezcla[x] =  s_array[indiceSarray];
     indiceSarray++;
   }
}


for (int x=0 ;x<mezcla.length;x++){
    System.out.print(mezcla[x] + " ");
}
```

Comment: me funciona completamente bien si pongo en todos los arrays "<.length" en vez de "<.length-1"  a que se debe?

Comment: Por que la condición es : i  < length , si fuera  i <=  , ahí si tendrías que usar length - 1

Comment: recuerda si la longitud de tu array es 3 , significa que puedes acceder a 0,1,2

Comment: Muchas gracias fuiste de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Como bien mencionan supongamos que `n` introduces `5` y `d = 10` cuando k llegue a 5, el indice en el arreglo p_array[5] no existe y te marcará el error.
Para solucionarlo puedes hacer esto

```
int mayor = n > d ? n : d; //verificamos que número es mayor
int[] mezcla = new int [mayor];
for (int k=0;k<mezcla.length;k++){
   if(n < k){
      System.out.print(p_array[k] + " ");
   }
   if(p < k){
      System.out.print(s_array[k] + " ");
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Me podrías explicar mejor el funcionamiento de la primera línea de código?

Comment: @Traxomax , la primera línea es un ternario, es lo mismo que if (n > d) mayor = n  else mayor = d;

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at arrays.Ej_5.main(Ej_5.java:43)                         Sigue dando excepcion

Comment: me equivoque en la validación, lo tenía como if(n < mayor){ y era if(n > mayor){, en ambas, ya los he cambiado en mi respuesta

Comment: pero entonces nunca va a entrar a ese bloque de codigo no? nunca ni n ni p van a ser >mayor

Comment: tienes razón lo siento, no tengo ahorita compliador de java, pero era por k en lugar de mayor, nuevamente edite el código corregido