# Mezclar dos arrays en uno (de tres en tres). Java

Tags: java, array

necesito mezclar dos arrays en uno cuyas longitudes las insertamos nosotros y que se llenan con randoms. La cuestión es que tengo que mezclarlos de la siguiente forma: tres primeros del primer array, tres primeros del segundo array, tres siguientes del primer array, tres siguientes del segundo array... etc, y no funciona bien mi codigo, a veces da excepcion

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at arrays.Ej_6.main(Ej_6.java:46)

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

```
package arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ej_6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce la dimension del primer array");
    int n=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduce la dimension del segundo array");
    int d=input.nextInt();

    int[] p_array = new int[n];
    int[] s_array = new int[d];

    for (int i=0;i<p_array.length;i++){
        p_array[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.print(p_array[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int j=0;j<s_array.length;j++){
        s_array[j]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.print(s_array[j] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();

    int[] mezcla = new int [n+d];
    int in_parray=0;
    int in_sarray=0;
    int x=0;

    for (x=0;x<mezcla.length;x++){
        if((x+2)%2==0 && in_parray<p_array.length){
            for (int k=0;k<3;k++){
                mezcla[x]=p_array[in_parray];
                in_parray++;
                x++;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println();
        if ((x+3)!=0 && in_sarray<s_array.length){
            for (int k=0;k<3;k++){
                mezcla[x]=s_array[in_sarray];
                x++;
                in_sarray++;
            }
        }

    }
    for (int z=0;z<mezcla.length;z++){
        System.out.print(mezcla[z] + " ");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Mezclar dos arrays en uno. Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121574/mezclar-dos-arrays-en-uno-java)

Comment: no, tengo que mezclarlos de tres en tres no de uno en uno

Comment: espero mi solución te ayude :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí lo tienes, no te olvides que siempre tienes que tener en consideración el índice al que vas a acceder, tu código se cae porque no funciona con array de menos de 3 elementos, revisa mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce la dimension del primer array");
    int n=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduce la dimension del segundo array");
    int d=input.nextInt();

    int[] p_array = new int[n];
    int[] s_array = new int[d];

    for (int i=0;i<p_array.length;i++){
        p_array[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.print(p_array[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int j=0;j<s_array.length;j++){
        s_array[j]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.print(s_array[j] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();

    int[] mezcla = new int [n+d];
    int in_parray=0;
    int in_sarray=0;
    int next_value_p = 3;
    int next_value_s = 3;

    for (int x=0;x<mezcla.length;x++){

        if(in_parray >= next_value_p && in_sarray >= next_value_s ){
            next_value_p+=3;
            next_value_s+=3;
        }

        if (in_parray < next_value_p && in_parray < p_array.length){
            mezcla[x] = p_array[in_parray];
            in_parray = in_parray + 1;
        }
        else
        if (in_sarray < next_value_s && in_sarray < s_array.length){
            mezcla[x] = s_array[in_sarray];
            in_sarray = in_sarray + 1;
        } 

    }

    for (int z=0;z<mezcla.length;z++){
        System.out.print(mezcla[z] + " ");
    }           
}
```